# Como debo relacionar dos tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda sobre cómo relacionar dos tablas.

[image: Foto de las tablas]

El problema es no sé qué tipo de relación crear para este ejemplo.

Teniendo en cuenta que en mi tabla COMBUSTIBLE tengo 2 registros:

```
IDcombustible | Combustible
---------------------------
    1         | Diesel
    2         | Gasolina
```

Ahora ingreso un motor y le asigno el tipo de combustible. El número 1 que es a diesel.

```
idmotor | tipo_motor | combustible_idcombustible
------------------------------------------------
1       | '2.5cc'    | 1
```

Ahora el problema es que necesito ingresar otro motor '2.5cc' pero existe a gasolina.

```
idmotor | tipo_motor | combustible_idcombustible
------------------------------------------------
1       | '2.5cc'    | 2
```

Al hacer eso me doy cuenta que nuevamente ingreso en la tabla MOTOR otro registro con la columna `tipo_motor` con el valor `'2.5cc'` pero con la columna `combustible_idcombustible` con valor 2. Creo que no es correcto por que hay redundancia de datos.

¿Cuál sería el modo correcto de relacionar las dos tablas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que necesitas crear una tabla adicional que soporte tu relación de muchos a muchos entre las tablas `motor` y `combustible`. Esto haría que tengas menor redundancia de datos. Así:

```
CREATE TABLE combustible_motor (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idCombustible INT NOT NULL,
    idMotor INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idCombustible) REFERENCES combustible (idCombustible),
    FOREIGN KEY (idMotor) REFERENCES motor (idMotor)
);
```

Y allí asocias los registros de ambas tablas.

```
INSERT INTO combustible_motor (idCombustible, idMotor) VALUES
(1, 1), -- el primer 1 refiere a tu combustible Diesel y el segundo 1 al motor de 2.5cc
(2, 1) -- el 2 refiere a tu combustible Gasolina y el 1 al motor de 2.5cc;
```

Por si acaso, hacer esto significa que vas a tener que remover la relación directa que hay entre tu tabla `combustible` hacia tu tabla `motor`.

Answer (score 2):

Un análisis de las siguientes preguntas nos puede indicar el camino: ¿Puede un motor utilizar distintos tipos de combustible? ¿Puede un combustible, ser utilizado en distintos motores? Si ambas respuestas son verdaderas, puedes utilizar una relación de "muchos a muchos" la cual hace uso de una tabla intermedia entre motor y combustible, por ejemplo motor_combustible, la cual contendría el id de motor y el id del combustible (quitando el id de combustible de la tabla motor).

De este modo, solo almacenarías las relaciones entre un motor y un combustible. Si quieres profundizar en como evitar la redundancia de datos, te invito a que investigues sobre la [normalización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos) de base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

Similar a lo que dijo Luiggi Mendoza, y sin dejar por alto el motor de la base de datos, puedes hacerlo con dos tablas, justo como en tu diagrama:

```
CREATE TABLE combustible(
    idcombustible INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    combustible VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
    )
    ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Tu segunda tabla quedaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE motor(
        idmotor INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        tipomotor VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        idcombustible INT(11) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (idcombustible ) REFERENCES combustible(idcombustible ) ON     DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE    
        )
        ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: aunque ya es viejo el tema y debe estar resuelto. yo le agregaría a la tabla, ambos sistemas de combustibles (diesel y gasolina), si el motor usa ambos combustibles agrego un (1) a cada campo y si solo usa 1 de los dos combustibles,  pones un 1 y al otro cero (0) y viceversa... a la hora de llamar la consulta, buscas por una o por otra o ambas...  si no tienes permisos para modificar las tablas, mi solución no te es util